# equivalent definitions of coprime ideals and their properties

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

In the ring of algebraic integers $R = \Bbb Z[\xi],\ \xi^2 + \xi + 1 = 0,$ i.e. $\xi = \frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$, I have seen three definitions for coprime ideals $(\alpha), (\beta) $:

$(1)\,\ $ Every common divisor of $ \alpha, \beta$ is a unit (invertible).

$(2)\,\ $ $ \alpha, \beta$ are not contained in a common maximal ideal.

$(3)\,\ $ The ideal sum $(\alpha)+(\beta)=(1)= R $

Are these three definitions equivalent? The inferences $(2) \Rightarrow  (3) \Rightarrow (1)\,$ are straightforward (cf. comments below), but what about $(1) \Rightarrow (3)$ or $(1) \Rightarrow (2)$. These can be done proved using [this Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2357893/242), but that requires extra work - showing that $R$ is a Euclidean domain or PID. Is this extra work necessary or is there another (general) method?

Comment: Equivalence of $2$ and $3$ is simple. If $A$ and $B$ are those ideals and if $A, B \subset M$ then $A + B \subset M$ so if $A + B = R$ then $A$ and $B$ are not contained in a common maximal ideal. Conversely if $A$ and $B$ are not contained in a common maximal ideal then $A + B$ must be $R$ otherwise the maximal ideal containing $A + B$ contains both of them.

Comment: The only reason 1 is equivalent to the rest is that $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ is a PID/UFD; if you change to the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, that equivalence no longer holds: the only elements that divide both $2$ and $1+\sqrt{-5}$ are units, but $(2)$ and $(1+\sqrt{-5})$ are both contained in $(2,1+\sqrt{-5})\neq R$.

Comment: See also [this Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2357893/242) on the equivalence with $(1)\ \ $

Comment: $3 \implies 1$ If $\lambda$ divides both of them then every element of $A + B$ is a multiple of  $\lambda$. Now $A + B = R$ means $1\in A + B$ so some multiple of $\lambda$ is $1$ i.e. $\lambda$ is a unit.

Comment: @Rishi, thank you. Yes, now we have (2) -> (3) -> (1), what about (1) -> (3) or (1) -> (2)

Comment: @BillDubuque I feel using that thm requires to prove that $Z[\xi]$ is Euclidean domain or PID which requires extra work.